# How to subscribe action in RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-kepler

I'm developing RCP application based on e4 compatibility layer.

**Question** is there any way so that i can subscribe any particular action (subscribe mean get notification).
For Example `CUT` or `COPY` action: when user select these option i want to get notify. So is there is any extension or some thing else to achieve this.

Comment: You might be able to subscribe to one (or more) of the `UIEvents` using the event broker, but documentation on the events is hard to find.

Comment: Hi @greg-449 I tried to subscribe all the TOPIC from `UIEvents` but its seems to me that there is no topic which is get the Action if they are executing. :(